# Azure WAF adds unwanted server http header

Tags: azure-application-gateway

The WAF appears to add a http header to each request with the following value:

`server:Microsoft-IIS/10.0`

This is a big problem for us as it causes us to fail penetration tests performed by 3rd parties who wish to use our service. Previously we use url rewrite module to remove server header, but by using the WAF it has added it back in.

Without getting into discussions about whether this is a security hole (I don't think it is), without us being able to control the response to the client we cannot pass this penetration test. Is there any option or do we have to abandon Azure WAF?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with the Application Gateway and therefore also the WAF, I've been told that it's being addressed in a coming release.

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/16487725-remove-server-framework-headers-from-application-g